# Datatable sort by references (with dot)

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using this datatable : https://datatables.net
My first column contain references like that : 1.1 or 1.2.1

So i am looking for a way to sort the table by references.
I was thinking about removing "." and get number like 11 or 121 which is easier to sort.

But I don't know, how can I remove the dot from the correct column (without showing anything to the user) and add "0" before sorting.

eg : If datas were : 1.1 1.1.1 1.2 1.2.1
 -> 110, 111, 120, 121

If datas were : 1.1 2.2.1.1 2.5
 -> 1100, 2211, 2500

Any help would be appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by a very simply type based sorting plugin. With a sorting plugin you can preprocess the content of a cell before it is sorted, or you can implement your own sorting algorithm. Here you just need to pass the "fixed" number back and then dataTables will sort as it was numbers :

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "reference-pre": function ( ref ) {
     ref = ref.replace(/\./g, '')      //remove dots
     while (ref.length < 4) ref += '0' //add 0 until length 4
     return parseInt(ref)              //return as number
  }
})
```

Usage :

```js
columnDefs : [
  { targets: 0, type: 'reference' }
]
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vc59bxww/**

Comment: It works fine thank you.
But I forgot to say that numbers are contained in a input...

Like : <input type="text" value="1.1">

Comment: @Snooze, That should be a nobrainer, use something like `ref = $(ref).val().replace(/\./g, '') `,

Answer (score 0):

i am using this way

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
 "formatted-num-pre": function ( a ) {
    
  a = (a === "-" || a === "") ? 0 : a.replace( '.', "" );
   
    return parseFloat( a );
  },

  "formatted-num-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return a - b;
  },

  "formatted-num-desc": function ( a, b ) {
    return b - a;
  }
  });

  $('#myTable').dataTable(
  {
  columnDefs: [
   { type: 'formatted-num', targets: 5 }
  ]
  });
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).